# AS2 Translate some Text to a Link

Tags: actionscript-2

I have a chat bubble, and I want it so when a user types a link it'll underline and become a hyperlink. I only have it working so that if the whole message is a link it'll work, but I want it so if it is a full message.

Example:
Currently, If I typed "http://hello.com" in a chat bubble it'll underline and link, but if I type "hi http://hello.com" it won't.

Any ideas on how I can do this? I'm not asking for code or anything because this forum is for helping, not asking people to make stuff for you.

Right now I'm thinking of HTML text.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I think you misunderstand the purpose of SO - it's not for helping to come up with ideas for a generic problem but to help with _specific_ issues in a specific bit of code. {http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you tried the HTML text ?